# Simulate multiple form clicks with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a product page on my website with product options, two with sub options.  For those options with sub options they are using type="radio"

I've created javascript buttons which emulate clicking those sub options.   I'd like to set up clearing the form and emulating the clicks all on one button.  Currently I have a separate clear button, which still doesn't work.

Picture Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5NuX.jpg

Code examples below

Sub option code:

```
<li class="option">
    <label for="09f0c74f3d92847ecfcf5837eb6b2f8b">
        <input type="radio" class="validation" name="attribute[249]" value="127" id="09f0c74f3d92847ecfcf5837eb6b2f8b"/>
        <span class="name">65cc</span>
    </label>
</li>
<li class="option">
    <label for="06fc48a0a3949a17c28162ea0eb1f406">
        <input type="radio" class="validation" name="attribute[249]" value="128" id="06fc48a0a3949a17c28162ea0eb1f406"/>
        <span class="name">75cc</span>
    </label>
</li>
```

First button:

```
<input onclick="document.getElementById('06fc48a0a3949a17c28162ea0eb1f406').click(); document.getElementById('a596a2e871da26ba9b1cf7fffe325848').click();" type="button" value="0911" />
```

Second button:

```
<input onclick="document.getElementById('09f0c74f3d92847ecfcf5837eb6b2f8b').click(); document.getElementById('a596a2e871da26ba9b1cf7fffe325848').click();" type="button" value="0916" />
```

Clear options:

```
<input onclick="Clear();" type="button" value="Clear" />
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function Clear()
{
clearRadioGroup("09f0c74f3d92847ecfcf5837eb6b2f8b");
clearRadioGroup("a596a2e871da26ba9b1cf7fffe325848");
}

function clearRadioGroup(GroupName)
{
var ele = document.getElementsById(GroupName);
for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
ele[i].checked = false;
}
// ]]></script>
```

In the above example the second button click would un-select the second element if the buttons were clicked in succession.  Thoughts on at the very least being able to clear the form?

Comment: I still don't understand what's your goal, except clearing the form.

Comment: Here is the form http://i.imgur.com/uAlLBAK.jpg

Basically when I clicked 0911 75cc and straight plug were selected.  If button 0917 is clicked it will simulate clicking 75cc and angle plug.  Since 75cc is already selected it will un-click 75cc and switch from straight plug to angle plug.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in function clearRadioGroup.  It should be 
"var ele = document.getElementById(GroupName);" and not 
"var ele = document.getElementsById(GroupName);". 
The Clear function will work then.

Comment: Just wanted to comment the issue is with my platform not accepting the code.  Thanks for the help!